# What is difference between the joint probability distribution and the sum/convolution, of 2 dists?

Tags: joint-distribution, convolution, sum

Google is coming up a bit short when I searched for "joint vs sum random variables".
Perhaps someone can provide an authoritative answer to compare and contrast the sum/convolution of 2 distributions vs the joint probability distribution?

Comment: This would be hard to answer because a sum of random variables and a joint probability distribution are completely different objects, both mathematically and conceptually.

Comment: True so maybe there isn't much compare and only contrast, or vice versa, but anything helps and will get an upvote for shore

Comment: Instead, might I suggest you research our [posts on joint distributions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22joint+distribution%22) and if--in conjunction with the duplicate post  on convolutions--you are still puzzling over some aspect of the distinction, edit this post to reflect your refined question.

Comment: akright, they are both distributions that result in combining two+ other distributions, so I am thinking there is plenty of compare to go with the contrast, nahmsayin? do it for search engines not just for me. I request an undo of the dupe call on OP, respectfully. It may be a stupid question, but it is a valid question and people should be free to answer it as they please. if nobody searches for it on google, it will not litter the internet.